# Complexity theory: Prove or disprove that $n^2\sin2n-5n=O(n^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, computer-science

So I have to show if $n^2\sin2n-5n={O(n^2)}$ holds true.

Now my idea was to try to solve it by taking the limit of the equation, i.e.:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n^2\sin2n-5n}{n^2}} =\lim_{n\to\infty}{(\sin2n-\frac{5}{n^2})}$

which as you can see doesn't help me much cause the limit is indeterminate.

After that I tried doing it with the definition:

There exists $n,k>0$, such that for every $n_0$ with $n_0>n$ it holds:

$n^2\sin2n-5n\leq kn^2$

After doing some operations we get: $\sin2n-\frac{5}{n}\leq k$

I started arguing that $|\sin2n|\leq1$, so the left side of the inequality is nearly always negative. But in the case of $n\to\infty$, $\frac{5}{n}\to 0$. So maybe you could make the argument that somehow the left side of the inequality can reach 1?

Now I'm kinda stuck here. For which $k$ and $n$ does the inequality hold? Considering what I wrote I think maybe for every $k>0$, independently from the value of $n$? Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are just about there.  Keep in mind you get to pick $k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$|n^2\sin(2n)-5n|\leq |n^2\sin(2n)|+|5n|\leq |n^2|+|5n|=n^2+5n\leq n^2+5n^2=6n^2$$

Since this is true for all $n\geq 1$ you are done. As an aside, to get a nice $\sin(x)$ do \$\sin(x)\$

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

For $ n_0>1 $,

$$\biggl|\frac{n_0^2\sin(2n_0)-5n_0}{n_0^2}\biggr|=$$

$$\biggl|\sin(2n_0)-\frac 5n_0\biggr|\le$$
$$|\sin(2n_0)|+\biggl|\frac 5n_0\biggr|\le 6$$

So $ n=1 $ and $ k=6$.

Comment: Oh damn, I get it!!! So the max value from the left side of the equation can never be bigger than 6, because max of $sin2n=1$ and max of $\frac{5}{n}=5$. Thanks!